# How to prove that $a^3 + b^3 \geq a^2b + ab^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Um I am solving problems in Arthur Engels book "Problem Solving Strategies". I was doing a problem from inequalities chapter, and I stumbled across a problem which I managed to condense and simplify into this:--

> For $a + b> 0$, $$a^3 + b^3 \geq a^2b + ab^2$$

I have no idea how to begin but this is what I did.

By A.M-G.M,
$$\frac{a^3 + a^3 + b^3}{3} \geq \sqrt[3]{a^3a^3b^3}$$
$$\implies a^3 + a^3 + b^3 \geq 3a^2b$$
...(i)
$$$$
$$\frac{b^3 + b^3 + a^3}{3} \geq \sqrt[3]{b^3b^3a^3}$$
$$\implies b^3 + b^3 + a^3 \geq 3ab^2$$
...(ii)

Now adding (i) and (ii) we have,
$$3a^3 + 3b^3 \geq 3a^2b + 3ab^2$$

Dividing everything by 3 we have,
$$a^3 + b^3 \geq a^2b + ab^2$$
Which is exactly what I wanted, but I have no idea whether this is correct. Please check it for me and please also tell if there are other methods to prove this.

(Also could you please invite I am very new to stackexchange and would like increase my reputation. Please.)

Comment: The traditional AM-GM inequality assumes non-negative numbers.  Here all you have is $a+b>0$, not that both are positive.  Hence you need to justify your use of AM-GM.

Comment: Consider $a=-2, b=3$. We have $a+b>0$, but $a^3+a^3+b^3=11<18=3a^2b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't apply AM-GM, as we need that $a,b\ge 0$ and not $a+b>0$.

Let's use the $a+b>0$ condition. Dividing by $a+b>0$ gives that it's enough to prove
$a^2-ab+b^2 \ge ab$
$\iff (a-b)^2 \ge 0$

The reason we divide is that we remember that $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$ since $a^n+b^n=(a+b)(a^{n-1}-a^{n-2}b+...+b^{n-1})$ for odd positive $n$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$a^3+b^3-(a^2b+ab^2)=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)-ab(a+b)=(a+b)(a-b)^2\ge0$$ if $a+b\ge0$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way of using AM-GM in this case:
$$a^3+b^3 = (a+b)(a^2+b^2-ab) \geqslant (a+b)(2ab-ab) = (a+b)ab = a^2b+ab^2$$

Answer (score 0):

Your proof is correct for $a,b>0$. This restriction comes from the condition of AM-GM inequality. You need to include more since the problem asks for the cases when $a+b>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note
$$\frac{a^3+b^3}{a^2b+ab^2}=\frac{a^2-ab+b^2}{ab}=\frac{(a-b)^2}{ab}+1\ge 1
$$
Thus
$$a^3+b^3\ge a^2b+ab^2$$

Comment: Looking at this answer, it's not immediately clear where $a+b>0$ is used. This condition means that the denominator is positive - and the direction of the inequality does not change when multiplying.

Comment: @MartinSleziak - that’s correct. Note that the condition should be $a,b>0$ instead.

Comment: The condition given was a + b>0 in arthur engels book. @Quanto.