How to prove $a^3+b^3>a^2b+b^2a$ inequality when $a>0$ and $b>0$
I proved this inequality by changing the inequality. Even though, I feel like my proof is accurate, I want to know if there is any other way to prove this inequality without altering it. From that I mean, is there a way to derive a relationship between $a$ and $b$ then apply it to the inequality to prove it, rather than manipulating the given inequality like I did.
Here's how I proved it:
$a≠b$
$a>0$
$b>0$
$∴$
$(a-b)^2>0$
and
$(a+b)>0$
Let's consider the inequality $a^3+b^3>a^2b+b^2a$
$(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)>ab(a+b)$
Since $(a+b)>0$,
$a^2-ab+b^2>ab$
$a^2-2ab+b^2>0$
$(a-b)^2>0$ : therefore the above inequality is proved true
P.S - I don't know if I am correct. I am looking for more of an answer that uses the cubic expansion of $(a+b)$: because I intuitively feel there is a relationship between those $a^3,b^3$ and $a^2b,b^2a$ terms

Related or duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3915822

This is a duplicate but to clarify, it is related more to squares, $a^3-a^2b+b^3-b^2a=(a^2-b^2)(a-b)\geqslant0$ as $t\mapsto t^2$ is monotone for positives.

You are correct.
$ a^3+b^3>a^2b+b^2a $ yes and only if $ (a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)>ab(a+b) $ and so on ... $(a-b)^2>0 $ but this is true.
